# Aframe - Get width and height of text <a-text> component

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am having trouble getting the height/width of an aframe text component within my custom aframe component. The text appears in my scene, I am able to console.log the 'geometry' & 'material' properties. However the geometry.layout properties is undefined despite the fact I can see it in my console.log! The 'layout' properties contains height and width, which is what I need. How can I get them ? 
Thanks for your help.

```
    const label = document.createElement('a-text');

    label.setAttribute('id', 'label');
    label.setAttribute('position', '0 0 0');
    label.setAttribute('value', 'Label test');
    label.setAttribute('color', 'black');

    label.addEventListener('object3dset', () => {
      const { material, geometry } = label.object3D.children[0];

      // Property geometry.layout is 'undefined' !!!
      console.log('LAYOUT', geometry.layout);
      console.log('LAYOUT_HEIGHT', geometry.layout.height);
      console.log('LAYOUT_WIDTH', geometry.layout.width);

      material.alphaTest = 0.5;
      material.transparent = true;
      material.depthTest = false;
      material.depthWrite = false;

    });
```

Comment: Not enough to be a proper answer but have you tried changing ‘object3Dset’ to ‘loaded’ in your listener?

Comment: I have just tried it, 'loaded' event is fired after the 'object3dset' event, however the geometry.layout property is still undefined. Cheers for your help Nich.